# findAny from nested List using Java Streams

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream, nested-lists

I need to find some object from nested `List`.

I believe the class code is not needed, because the filtering is exposed in nested `For-Each Loop`.

```
int value = someValue;

MyObject found = null;
for (List<MyObject> list : nestedList) {
  for (MyObject myObject : list) {
    if (myObject.isType() && myObject.getValue() == value) {
      found = myObject;
    }  
  }
}
```

The other nested for is:

```
List<MyObject> listMyObject = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<MyObject> list : nestedList) {
  for (MyObject myObject : list) {
    if (myObject.isType() && myObject.getValue() == value) {
      listMyObject.add(myObject);
    }  
  }
}
```

I started with this code, but I'm confused.

```
nestedList.stream()
.forEach(list -> list.stream()
         .filter(myObject -> myObject.isType() && myObject.getValue() == value)
         .findAny()
);
```

**How replace the `For-Each Loop` in my code using Streams?**

The solution for second loop `for`

```
listMyObject = nestedList.stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .filter(myObject -> myObject.isType() && myObject.getValue() == value)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findAny` as:

```
MyObject found = nestedList.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(myObject -> myObject.isType() && myObject.getValue() == someValue)
        .findAny()
        .orElse(null);
```

though your actual code ensures the selection of last found object since you override the object every time the conditions are met.

Comment: Thanks Good uses for `flatMap`, Can Use this for my second nested `for`?

Comment: @QA_Col The `flatMap` along with `stream` is reducing your nested lists to a stream of objects altogether.

Comment: If finding the last one really is required, simply replacing `findAny()` with `reduce((a,b) -> b)` would do. Though this is rarely required.

Answer (score 0):

This helps for your second loop

```
List<List<Integer>> inner=Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3),Arrays.asList(4,2,6));

List<Integer> optinner= inner.stream().flatMap(List::stream).filter(integer -> 
integer==2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```